# <li> jquery click doesnt trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something once a users clicks on an < li> element. For some reason nothing happens:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="settings" id="mitmachen">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i><i class="icon-right-open"></i> Mitmachen</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


  $("mitmachen").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('hi');
      $("#participate .section").removeClass('hide');
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe its too late :D

Comment: also this click event should be wrapped in jquery ready function

Comment: It is wrapped in a ready, I just took the snippet. But for some reason the # (which I tried before doesnt work either).

Comment: Looks like it works to me... are you getting the 'hi' alert with the # to denote the ID? 
Working: http://jsfiddle.net/83sa3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery, `$("mitmachen")` searches for an element with the *tag* `mitmachen` (like `div` or `span`). jQuery uses CSS-style selectors. To search for an element by `id`, use `#`: `$("#mitmachen")`

Comment: Good explanation. For some reason it still doesnt work.

Comment: @user2942586: You must have a typo somewhere, you're already doing the other thing that would make this seem not to work (the `e.preventDefault()`), so it should just be the above. Working here: http://jsbin.com/lasum/1 This is provided the code is in the order shown in your question, e.g., the code is in a `script` element *below* the `mitmachen` element in the HTML (if it's above it, and not wrapped in a `ready` handler or similar, then the element won't exist yet when you try to hook it up -- move the script below [usually just before the closing `</body>` tag is good]).

Comment: The editor for some reason did not write the file, so the changes were not uploaded to my server. Another good reason to use Github. So annoying. Thanks for your help, it works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `#` here

```
    $("mitmachen").click(function(e) {
```

It should be

```
    $("#mitmachen").click(function(e) {
```